# how to get the difference between 2 dates with Dql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

How can I get the difference between 2 dates with Dql?

I have tried the following code, but that didn't work.

```php
$query =$this->_em->createQuery('select a,DATEDIFF(d,\'now\',a.date) from ABundle:Abonment a where d==1');
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From this source http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions:

`DATE_DIFF(date1, date2)` - Calculate the difference in days between date1-date2, and in your query your function is taken 3 parameters.

In Doctrine2 you have to use one of the following functions that fits better on you instead of now() function:

```
CURRENT_DATE() - Return the current date
CURRENT_TIME() - Returns the current time
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - Returns a timestamp of the current date and time.
```

On conclusion your query should by something like:

```
$query =$this->_em->createQuery('select a, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), a.date) as days from ABundle:Abonment a where days = 1');
```